# Error while trying to open .tif file with PIL ImageTk

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to display images in a tkinter GUI, but I can't open .tif images with ImageTk.

This is not the code inside the GUI itself, but this code already gives me the error: raise OSError(err); OSError: -2

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

path = "X00_No_01_LOM.tif"

load = Image.open(path)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = load)
```

I already tried changing the name of the image to .tiff but it doesn't work either. I found out now that it has to do with that particular image, because I can load other .tif images. It also doesn't work if I convert it to another format like png. Those images are saved as a.tif using the function cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask).

Comment: Does the file exist in the current working directory?

Comment: Yes, it does. I found out now that it has to do with that particular image, because I can load other .tif images

Comment: Maybe something to do with read permissions then?

Comment: I don't know. But they are images that I created in python applying masks to a tiff image with openCV

Comment: It may be the ouput format of the function cv2.cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask). I am saving that as a .tif